# pyqt: add and display item in QListView if checked in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview, qlistview

In `QTreeView` I display data with `QAbstractItemModel` as shown in figure below. [image: QTreeView and QListView]

I would like to display item in `QListView` if it is checked in `QTreeView`. Do I have to create a new model view with only selected data or can I use tree model (data) and only create model view with existing data?

**AnalysisWidget**

```
class AnalysisWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data=None, parent=None):
        super(AnalysisWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.data = data_

        #    tree model view
        #    set model
        _model = AnalysisTreeModel(self.data._children[0].parameters)
        #    set model of tree view
        self.ui.treeView.setModel(_model)

        #    list model view
        #    set model
        _model = AnalysisListModel(self.data._children[0].parameters)#
        #    set model of table view
        self.ui.listView.setModel(_model)
```

Comment: Have one model, and use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) on the list-view.

Comment: @ekhumoro After some thoughts I found that I have to use `QTableView` instead of `QListView`. Where first 3cols will have some informations and than each next column will represent mean value of selected parameter and the name of the selected parameter is appended to column headers. This should work with your suggestion ie, `QSortFilterProxyModel`?

Comment: A `QTreeView` can display a flat list with columns, so you might not need `QTableView`. That might make it easier to implement the `QSortFilterProxyModel`.